# joining two table inputs in a single transaction

Tags: pentaho, business-intelligence, kettle, spoon, geokettle

[image: my ktr]Hi, I am trying to create a kettle transaction where the data is read from two tables and then joined. Above seems to be very simple and basic transformation but i get an issue when trying to do it in a single transaction i.e. with "make the transformation database transactional" enabled in transformation settings. The below exception is reported when trying to do so-

com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@7c02dce0 is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.

Answer (score 1):

if the data source comes from the same database try to do a single query step, do your query doing the join tables in the sql query, after that you will not need the merge join step, and the transaction will be atomic.

Comment: is there any other alternative for this? Doing this would require a considerable amount of rework...also writing SQL for joins would make the transformation database speific, for example-there is no "outer join" in my sql

Comment: well, if you are only doing reads, selects, disable the "make the transformation database transactional" option, unless you want to do this transformation for extremely real time high frequency and your db input data changes in seconds.

Comment: is there a way to make the jobs transactional in the community version?